# Enabling Twig strict variables with Timber

Tags: timber

I'm running the latest version of Timber (0.22.5).

Is there a way that I can enable [`strict_variables`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options) for Twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out – stick this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function theme_configure_twig($twig) {
    $twig->enableStrictVariables();
    return $twig;
}
add_filter('get_twig', 'theme_configure_twig');
```

Note that in the above, `$twig` refers to Timber's instance of [`Twig_Environment`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Environment.html).